# Node REPL eval Callback

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I have a small sample program http://pastebin.com/5gFkaPgg that serves a REPL to a client over TCP. Acording to the docs http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html I have by eval function (lines 11-13) setup correctly, but the callback object is not a function. What am I misinterpreting in the docs?

```
  callback(null,result);
  ^
TypeError: object is not a function
```

Can't Answer my own question...

According to https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/repl.js
the signature is

```
function(code, context, file, cb) {
  //code
  cb(err, result);
}
```

Let me know if there is a more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error and the signature tells me that the callback was given as its arguments `(code, context, file, cb)` but expected as its arguments `(code, cb)` and thus `context` was bound to `cb` and as `context` is not a function, the error was produced.

You need to do is change the argument list of the callback given to `repl.start` to:

```
function(cmd, context, file, callback) {
```

or use the common:

```
function(cmd) {
  var callback = arguments[arguments.length-1]; // get the last argument
```

Code with the second option as it introduces no new names:

```
var net = require('net');
var repl = require('repl');

function main() {
  var clients = [];

  net.createServer(function(socket) {
    clients.push(socket);

    repl.start(">", socket, function(cmd) {
      var callback = arguments[arguments.length-1];
      var result = cmd;

      callback(null,result);
    });
    socket.on('end',function() {
      clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket));
    });
  }).listen(8000);
}

main();
```

Comment: Nailed it. FWIW the incorrect docs [have been fixed in HEAD](https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/2884).