# Node.js REPL eval

Tags: sockets, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I am trying to implement an evaluation into a Node.JS REPL. I am getting the error `TypeError: Property 'eval' of object #<REPLServer> is not a function`. Here is my source code:

```
repl.start("> ", socket, socket, true, function(cmd, context, filename, callback){
etc...
```

Comment: See [Node REPL eval Callback][1] answer. Which explains how you might use the first approach.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713247/node-repl-eval-callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

repl.start() takes an object with those options, not individual arguments:

e.g. (note the curly brackets)

```
repl.start({
  prompt: "node via stdin> ",
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});
```

see the example at: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.4/api/repl.html#repl_repl_start_options